# Is it possible to have different colored graphs in a single series in HighCharts?

Tags: javascript, colors, highcharts

I have a single series column graph with x-axis as datetime and y-axis as some constant value. I would like to show the columns in different colors based on some information I have , is this possible ?

e.g. I have dynamic data coming in to plot my graph,I use `series.addPoint({x:x,y:value,extra:info}, false, false)` to plot the same. Based on the info, how can I vary the colors?

I am pretty new to javascript and highcharts. So pardon my limited knowledge, any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

Updated code:

```
 if(type=='a')
    color='#7cb5ec';
else
    if(type=='b')
        color='#f45b5b';
    else
        if(type=='c')
            color='#8085e9';
        else
            if(type=='d')
                color='#2b908f';
            else
                color='#e4d354';
series.addPoint({x:x,y:value,extra:info,marker:{fillColor:color}}, false, false);
```

I have also set the `colorByPoint: true` option. The series.addPoint function runs in a loop which runs as and when I get my data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out the following

```
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    colorByPoint: true
                }
            },
            colors: [
                '#7cb5ec', '#434348', '#90ed7d', '#f7a35c', '#8085e9', 
                '#f15c80', '#e4d354', '#2b908f', '#f45b5b', '#91e8e1'
            ],
```

[Fiddle link :)](http://jsfiddle.net/u3Lpnu5x/)

Update 1:

[Dynamic series fiddle:)](http://jsfiddle.net/p7uLj50s/)

Update 2:

Use the following code to have specific color for specific bar

```
chart.series[0].addPoint({y: Math.random() * 100, color:'#659355'}, true, true);
```

Comment: Thanks @Pandiyan . I have dynamic data coming in to plot my graph,I use series.addPoint({x:x,y:value,extra:info}, false, false) to plot the same. Based on the info, how can I vary the colors?

Comment: Yes right. Only thing is I use series.addPoint({x:x,y:value,extra:info}, false, false)  and need only 5 colors. Anyway where we could pass color value into the addPoint function above ?

Comment: You need specific colors for specific points or random colors from 5 colors?

Comment: Can you just check the updated code in my question, if theres any mistake in that. I am setting specific colors for specific points but the result is not what I need.

Comment: series.addPoint({x:x,y:value,extra:info, color: value}, false, false)

Comment: if possible provide me fiddle link

Comment: @Abbas check updated answer and make changes as per in answer

Comment: Thanks Pandiyan for all your help :) I was able to fix it with series.addPoint({x:x,y:value,extra:info,color:chartcolor}, false, false);

Answer (score 0):

You also can put `colorByPoint: true` in `series` option.

This way I do in my project, share for whom concern.

```
plotOptions: {
      series: {
        pointWidth: 30,
        colorByPoint: true,
        dataLabels: {
          format: '{point.y:.0f}억원',
          enabled: true,
          align: 'right',
          color: '#FFFFFF',
          x: -5,
          y: 3,
          style: {
            fontSize: "16px",
            color: '#fff',
            fontWeight: '500',
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
colors: Array(3).fill().map(()=>`#${Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16)}`)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).